# The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView on the child's parent first

Tags: android

I'm getting following error 
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        web  = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

        ln1=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ln1);

        WebSettings settings =  web.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        web.loadUrl("http://github.tkddnjsdja.tk/");
        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());

        web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

            public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);

            }



        });

        setContentView(web);

    }
```

seems like setcontentView is the problem
but not sure how to fix this and make it work.

Comment: on which line does the exception happen?

Comment: setContentView(web);

Comment: ok, I see on which line. Why you do this `setContentView(web);`? You have already set the content view on the beginning.

Comment: Add a stacktrace

Comment: Remove ths line `setContentView(web);`

Answer (score 1):

You get the exception because you try to add the view, which is already added.

When you call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` your layout is added to the application's window (root view). Then you do `web  = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);` - get the WebView, and process it. The webView is already added to your screen.

After that you try to add it again: `setContentView(web);`. You shouldn't do that since your webView is already added.

Also call this line

```
web.loadUrl("http://github.tkddnjsdja.tk/");
```

**after** you set the clicnts to the `WebView`, not **before**.